# is it possible to make a database out of a doc or txt file?

Tags: database, file, text, import

I'm just too new to android !

I want to make a really really simple application with a column of buttons in main activity which each one opens a new activity and they have got some long texts in them.
its a simple app just some texts.
so if it is possible with which codes ? and what steps i can do it ?
please be clear cause i do not know much i want to learn some simple tasks
 so tell how to import a text file if its possible ?? 
or should i just use string.xml and this is the only correct way to do it ??

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your best solution would be as follows. I'm assuming the text is static, and you already have it in txt files.

Store your text files in the application in paths similar to `res/raw/textfile.txt`.

To access these files, use code similar to the following. The `R.raw.textfile` determines which file will be opened, so be sure to have that change depending on the item the user selected in the main activity.

```
// Call the LoadText method and pass it the resourceId
LoadText(R.raw.textfile);

public void LoadText(int resourceId) {
    // The InputStream opens the resourceId and sends it to the buffer
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String readLine = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(readLine);
        }

    // Close the InputStream and BufferedReader
    is.close();
    br.close();

    //Do something with result.toString(); (set a text view's content to result.toString())

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer / oh okay ofc its for java....just how the xml file should be for this ??

Comment: You shouldn't have to use an xml file like strings.xml for this. You should just be able to put the `txt` files in the `res` folder and they should be accessible automatically! PS, please select me as the accepted answer if this helps :)

Comment: okay my question is how should i call that mtq.txt into myfile.xml ? i did the codes as you said in myfile.java .

Comment: when i put my codes into `strings.xml` i call them in textview by `android:id="@+id/` so how should i bring them `myfile.xml` to use them?

Comment: Sorry Androidman, I'm not quite understanding. I don't think you need `myfile.xml`. It is confusing that you are able to use `R.raw.textfile` as an ID to reference the textfile, but that is automatically generated by your project. If a text file exists in `/res/raw/`, it will have a corresponding reference ID `R.raw.*`.

Sorry if this isn't answering your question properly.

If you would like to use `strings.xml`, you can, but I wouldn't recommend it and it would require a different method.

Comment: ok, i want to press a button in main activity (the first page of my app) and this button opens a page (the 3rd layout in my project which is in a file in xml obviously ) now i want to show the text in `res/raw` folder to be showed in this page after button

Comment: Hey, no worries. I'd be happy to try and help more. Your question is more clear.

You'll need to access the `TextView` you specified in your 3rd layout. You can do so with [Activity.findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById). Once you've programatically found your text view, you can insert the the `result.toString()` I mentioned in the comment in the above code. Use [TextView.setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to do this.